# Getting This Particular Error "chrome did not shut down correctly"

Tags: google-chrome

I keep getting the error :

> Restore pages Chrome didn’t shut down correctly

every time I open chrome after it crashes. When I click on the **“restore pages”** option, chrome does not bring back the earlier opened pages.
I do not know what triggers this error. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Restore pages Chrome didn’t shut down correctly]

Answer (score 0):

So, I search the internet for this issue and found this [here](https://digicruncher.com/chrome-didnt-shut-down-correctly/). After preventing chrome from running apps after closing it fix the issue. Hopefully, this will help others also.